# c# Script to login and download from Kaggle

Tags: c#, webclient, kaggle

Recently, I came across a python script to download files directly from Kaggle : https://ramhiser.com/2012/11/23/how-to-download-kaggle-data-with-python-and-requests-dot-py/

I am trying to do something similar using WebClients in C#. I've came the following response in StackOverFlow : [C# download file from the web with login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758917/c-sharp-download-file-from-the-web-with-login)

Tried using it but I seem to be downloading only the login page instead of the actual file. Here's my main code :

```
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
CookieAwareWebClient http = new CookieAwareWebClient(cookieJar);

string postData = "name=<username>&password=<password>&submit=submit";
string response = http.UploadString("https://www.kaggle.com/account/login", postData);
Console.Write(response);

http.DownloadFile("https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/train.csv", "train.CSV");
```

I've used the Webclient extension from the link above and modified slightly :

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }

    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    {
    }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = cookies;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        this.Uri = address;
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
        httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        return httpRequest;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse r = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        var response = r as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response != null)
        {
            CookieCollection cookies = response.Cookies;
            CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Was wondering if anyone can point out where I went wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have created a forum post to help you accomplish what you wanted to do,  [Accessing Kaggle API through C#](https://www.kaggle.com/general/52093).  Feel free to post here or on the forum if you have additional questions.

Comment: Hei Peijen, thanks for the update. When I tried to use the sample code provided, I seem to be downloading the files with the following content : "System.Net.Http.WinHttpResponseStream" only. Happens for all files and I've tried with both the project in the sample code and the infamous Titanic project. Do you know why this is happening?

ps: I've tried using both .Net framework and .Net core and the results are the same.

Comment: Jeremy, I have updated the code to use FileStream instead of StreamWriter, try that and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. I'm getting a "stream does not support writing". I can't set the position either.

Comment: Did you use "stream.CopyTo(output);"  Instead of "output.Write(stream);"  Sorry I didn't call it out in the previous comment.  If that still doesn't work do you mind posting your code somewhere and I can take a look.

Comment: Yeap, I noticed that. Here's a link to the file itself : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E3ryHnBDSGL-HoSBMQsOeGOBI8sd37aj/view?usp=sharing

I've pretty much js copied and paste the code you had in your sample in this case

Comment: ah, you want **stream**.CopyTo(output) not **output**.CopyTo(stream)

Comment: gaah, I can't believe I missed that. It's working now. thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/train.csv by your browser without logged in and your browser will open that page instead of downloading your file. You need to put direct link to the file instead of a web page.

Your code works perfectly, you just need to put a direct link to that file or make sure you have logged in before download the file.

Comment: Hey Red, yeap you are correct that it needs a login before being able to download.

Hence, I understood that by calling this method http.UploadString(..), the WebClientExtension logs in, saves the cookie so that the next time I try to access a page or download the file via http.DownloadFile(...), it uses the cookie to access the direct link but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: This `string postData = "name=<username>&password=<password>&submit=submit";`. It's not always is "name" and "password", you need to view the web cookies and follow their pattern. Try `string postData = "UserName=<username>&Password=<password>`

Comment: Yeap, played around with it but didn't manage to get through . I suppose I'll try the API and see if I can get a better result. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you were asking, but [Kaggle now has an official API](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) that you can use to download data. Should be a bit easier to use. :)

Comment: thanks Rachael for the info. However, the API is available for python while I'm trying to use c# directly to get the files.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I don't think there are any plans in the works to release a c# API, but I'll pass it on.